# Agent loading fine but instrumentation not occuring

Tags: java, bytecode, loader, instrumentation

In order to load and attach my agent to a process the following statement `vm.loadAgent("pathToAgent","");` executes properly as no exception is thrown. But the class files responsible for instrumentation are not working it seems.

The class files contained in this agent `jar` just reconstructs each class file and printing the name of each class file in the process.

While using the same agent for doing instrumentation by executing a program with this agent it works fine.